# Scroll to top of page

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple way to force the browser to scroll to the top if a button is clicked?

I have tried

```
jQuery('html').scrollTop();
jQuery('body').scrollTop();
jQuery(window).scrollTop();
```

None of them seem to scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: This is because [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) doesn't actually scroll the page unless given a value; without a value it just returns a pixel value representing the *scroll position* as an offset from the *top* of the page.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Due to cross browser oddness, some browsers will respond to `'html'` and some to `'body'`. And maybe its just my luck, but `.scrollTop(0)` has never worked for me to move the page. Give this a shot:

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
```

This version is tested and cross browser for all desktop browsers, and mobile devices.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Wasn't able to get it to break in FF, IE or Safari.  Haven't checked chrome yet.  Thank you!

Comment: Btw, I have tried this code too. It works for me. But was thinking that css tricks is a great name and may be them have put a long code for a reason :) Thanks for clarifying :)

I loved the mario's answer too :)

Comment: CSS tricks is a rocking blog, from which I have learned alot, but I still get to disagree with 'em sometimes ;)

Comment: You are a star.

Answer (score 33):

Simple pure javascript, also works in mobile

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Comment: Simplest and cross platform solution. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can use either this:

```
jQuery('body').scrollTop(0);
```

or this:

```
jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
```

or finally this:

```
jQuery('html').scrollTop(0);
```

So, in order to call the [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method and make your page scrolling you should pass an argument with the numeric value representing the scrollTop position. Otherwise it will work as if you need to get the scrollTop position.

Two last methods should work constantly in all browsers, while the first might not work in some versions of IE.

Comment: I could not get 'body' to work, but 'html' worked as long as I passed in 0.  Do you know if these are cross browser or which version this method won't work in by chance?

Comment: @JamesWilson See my answer for a simple cross browser solution.

Comment: @JamesWilson It really depends. You can try method of Fresheyball but without animate, simply: `jQuery('html, body').scrollTop(0);`

Comment: I went with Freshey's it seemed to work across all browsers.  Thank you for your answer as well they did indeed work.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody mentioned the required HTML I'll add it here.

First create your anchor element:

`<a href="#" title="Scroll to Top" class="ScrollTop">Scroll To Top</a>`

Note the class is referenced by the following jQuery.

Then add your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ScrollTop').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
  return false;
    });
});
```

To adjust the speed of the animation change the "800" value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cross browser way,

```
function scrollableElement(els) {
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
        var el = arguments[i],
        $scrollElement = $(el);
        if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
            return el;
        } else {
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
            var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
            if (isScrollable) {
                return el;
            }
        }
    }
    return [];
}

var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

$(scrollElem).scrollTop(0);
```

*Code from css-tricks*

Comment: Do you know if this method id better than Fresheyeball's below?  Or do they do about the same thing as far as browser consistancy?

Comment: @JamesWilson they do basically the same thing, except this method goes through the unnecessary work of determining `'body'` or `'html'` before using it. Frankly it alot of extra code for the solution.