# pagination to top of page

Tags: php, pagination, page-jump

i have a search page and want to show numbered links for number of pages found.

for the top of the page i have:

```
         <ul class="pagination"></ul>
```

for bottom of the page:

```
        <ul class="pagination"><li><a class="active">1</a></li><li><a href="#">2</a></li><li><a class="">3</a>
```

this is working, except for the bottom part which will link to the next page (2 or 3) in correct way, but it stays on bottom of the page.
Is there a way to have it jump to the top of the page?
I tried with href="#" but this is not working (instead of class="") can be seen for page 2 in the code, also #top is not working.
Any hints or ideas?
Thanks
Stefan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to top of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745485/scroll-to-top-of-page).

Comment: Try it again with #top, but create an element at the top of the page <a name="top"></a>

Comment: i tried with the element but still stays on bottom of the page...